# Difference between Landing Page and Starting Page

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, marketing, viral-marketing

This question is regarding Google Analytics Behavior Flow. 
What is the difference between a **landing page** and a **starting page**?

I can't find a definite answer anywhere. Some people have suggested the following:

"Landing page is the first page from the visitor’s first session.
Start Page is the first page from the visitor’s session."

I don't know what that means, if the landing page is the first page from the visitors session wouldn't it automatically be the start page? That is true most of the time but I have landing pages that connect to different starting pages on my Behavior Flow. See attached image.

Please, if you answer this make sure to include some examples so I can understand it better.

[image]